# "Screen-states": How to express all of them in a concise way?

Tags: uml, gui, modeling, diagrams

If my software has some screens, how do i express the various states of those screens? If, for example, I have 3 checkboxes in a screen, so I have 8 combinations total and at first thought, 8 states for that screen. What if there is a popover widget, a slide, etc... And all this variations combined represent many and many states of a single screen.

My software could have only 20 screens, but could have 2000 or an indefinite number of "state-screens".

How do I represent all that in a concise way? Is there some diagram for this? Like UML diagrams are used for functional aspects of the program and how they are going to be implemented, and for UI? Are there any User Interface Modeling Language of sorts?

Comment: Could I ask why do you need to express all of possible states of your screens please? I don't see any benefits of getting to draw all of them.

Comment: What exactly do you want to represent? To sketch a UI you can use dedicated tools or any drawing tool. But it has nothing to do with the states, you just show controls position. What is the point of drawing "all" states? With UI you just show position of controls/fields. Behaviour, data structure etc goes to UML model.

Answer (score 1):

In UML (or any other type of practical design) you will never have to design every single possible combination of states, as you pointed out, that's impossible.

UML is meant to model something, and that's it. It doesn't force you you to come up with every single possible mix of states.

The designer or UX person will generally need to keep in mind 3 different states for every component:

1/ empty state
2/ non-empty state
3/ error state

Generally a composition of the different components will be presented as a means to cover general use cases. For example, you can have a form of 5 text boxes, it's sufficient that the design provides 1 example of how an empty text box state looks like, and 1 example of an error state. It's complete madness to have 5*3 states in different combinations with each other, there's just no added value in that, on the contrary.

If you have a pop-over, or any other component, follow the same rules. A rule of thumb really is to make a default set of rules of how your components behave, and then you don't need to worry about the combination of those components too much.

For example if you define a modal screen, as a screen that pops up in the middle of the window, and has a z-index that is higher than anything else, and on top of that, only type of modal can be active, then you've defined a good set of rules to make sure that that modal will behave very predictable (depending on your use case) just by defining rules of that specific component, without worrying about other components.

So keep things very granular! Don't go mixing different combinations into a specific "state" that you need to define special rules for, that's only going to give you added complexity you actually don't need.

Comment: It is actually possible, and practical, to specify combinations of states, using Petri nets.

Comment: I had to look up PT nets, how I understood the question his question was more in a visual - design - way, although mentioning UML diagrams, it was focused on "all" the different components (modals, pop-over, sliders, ...) ... Can you give an example of how that would work in the question he put out? I understood his question more of how to come to an overview of behaviour, which you can indeed do with PT nets, but having 20 screens... wouldn't that be overkill and just go with a UX / design approach first?